# How do I get an error's body which contains more error message detail using forge-api for nodejs?

Tags: javascript, node.js, autodesk-forge

I'm having problem finding for a way to get the body when the API request returns an error.  I have tested creating a bucket with capital letters and all I get is an error object which has `statusCode = "400"` and `statusMessage = "BAD REQUEST"`.

Based on forge API, I'm suppose to get a more detailed message on what went wrong from the `body` but I do not know how to access it using forge-api.

Below is an example of the forge-api call:

```
  var bucketsApi = forgeSDK.BucketsApi();
  var postBuckets = new forgeSDK.PostBucketsPayload();
  //bucketKey = "Ab" which should throw bad request error due to bucket key not allowing uppercase
  postBuckets.bucketKey = req.body.bucketKey; 
  postBuckets.policyKey = "transient";

  bucketsApi.createBucket(postBuckets, {}, oauth.OAuthClient(), credentials).then(function (buckets) {
            res.status(200).end();
        }).catch(function (error) {                                
                res.status(err.statusCode); //400
                res.write(err.statusMessage); //BAD REQUEST
                //missing error reason "Valid field 'bucketKey' must be of the form  [-_.a-z0-9]{3,128}"
                res.end();                
        });
```

Comment: try `` res.write(err)``

Comment: `err` only have `err.statusCode` and `err.statusMessage` and nothing else...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At https://github.com/Autodesk-Forge/forge-api-nodejs-client,
I can see that they are using node-js "request" module and only returning `statusCode` and `statusMessage`.
Hence, You can't get more than these two fields.

Comment: Wow, good catch and thanks for pointing me to the right direction.  Guess I'll have to modify the module myself and maybe, submit a pull request if it's working for me. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can fork forge-api-nodejs-client and modify.